# How to do a IN from a list in string format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with SQL management Studio 2014. I have SQL table like :

`sql_Type`  |  `sql_Name`  |  `sql_Parent`

I want to get all `sql_Type` who have specific parent. My variable `@listParents` is nvarchar(MAX) and contains all parents separated with a ';'.

How can I do ? I have the beginning but I don't know what to write in my `IN` :

```
DECLARE @listParents nvarchar(MAX) = 'Parent1;Parent2;Parent3;';

SELECT sql_Name
FROM [myTable]
WHERE sql_Type = 'Box' AND sql_Parent IN
(
    -- What should I do wjth @listParents ?
)
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: @IgorCova i edited my question, I'm working with SQL management studio 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MSSQL (< SQL server 2016):**

You can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) to solve this:

```
DECLARE @listParents nvarchar(MAX) = 'Parent1;Parent2;Parent3;'

SELECT sql_Name
FROM test
WHERE sql_Type = 'Box' AND CHARINDEX(sql_Parent + ';', @listParents) > 0;
```

> *demo:* http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64a6b/10/0

**MSSQL (>= SQL server 2016):**

Since SQL server 2016 you can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and `IN` to solve this:

```
DECLARE @listParents nvarchar(MAX) = 'Parent1;Parent2;Parent3;'

SELECT sql_Name
FROM test
WHERE sql_Type = 'Box' AND sql_Parent IN (
    SELECT value  
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@listParents, ';')  
    WHERE RTRIM(value) <> ''
);
```

> *demo:* http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64a6b/9/0

Comment: I'm working with Sql Management Studio 2014 and I have an error 'FIND_IN_SET doesn't exist'

Comment: so change your tags (`mysql-management`). and add the tags for dbms too.